# Does HBaseTestingUtility work at all with a MiniCluster?

Tags: hbase, hbasetestingutility

I have a simple unit test I want to run against the `HBaseTestingUtility` MiniCluster.  The transitive dependencies needed to run a test with `HBaseTestingUtility` are missing.  I've been tracking down `NoClassDefFoundErrors` and have run into something that may be an error in the packaging of one of the jar files.  Here's the error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/test/MetricsAssertHelper
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.<init>(MiniHBaseCluster.java:91)`

When I search for MetricsAssertHelper in the .jar files in my project I find that file under the META-INF/services directory:

`jar tvf org/apache/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat/1.0.0/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.0.0-tests.jar | grep MetricsAssertHelper
    53 Sat Feb 14 19:43:40 MST 2015 META-INF/services/org.apache.hadoop.hbase.test.MetricsAssertHelper
  1337 Sat Feb 14 19:43:40 MST 2015 org/apache/hadoop/hbase/test/MetricsAssertHelperImpl$MockMetricsBuilder.class
  3743 Sat Feb 14 19:43:40 MST 2015 org/apache/hadoop/hbase/test/MetricsAssertHelperImpl$MockRecordBuilder.class
  6689 Sat Feb 14 19:43:40 MST 2015 org/apache/hadoop/hbase/test/MetricsAssertHelperImpl.class`

This is not a .class file, however.  I wonder if the`MetricsAssertHelper.class` file is missing from the .jar file since there is a 'MetricsAssertHelperImpl.class file` there.

Here is my code and mvn dependencies.  The Error happens on the `HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster()` call.

```
    private static HBaseTestingUtility utility; 

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    utility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
    utility.startMiniCluster();
}


    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-hadoop2-compat</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I also needed a dependency for `hbase-hadoop-compat` in addition to `hbase-hadoop2-compat`.  Here is the complete list of dependencies needed to run JUnit tests with HBaseTestingUtility MiniCluster.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-hadoop-compat</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-hadoop2-compat</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: All dependencies should have <scope>test</scope>

Comment: Why not just add the following:

org.apache.hbase:hbase-testing-util:1.1.1

?